# Base file for certain formatting

Tags: packages, amsart, preamble

I'm interested in making a latex text and using the following template as shown below:

[image]

This text is in Portuguese, the "Sumário" translation is the Summary, and the "Introdução" is the Introduction and where it is blurred is the author.

I would like some tips to leave the base file with the preamble that gives rise to the image text style.

I tried to do something that looked like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\title{Teorema de Stokes}
\maketitle
\begin{center}
\author{MATEUS EDUARDO SALOMÃO}
\end{center}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introdução}

\section{Preliminares}

\end{document}
```

How do I make the author smaller? And the lowercase letters in the Summary?

Comment: Looks like the `amsart` class.